# Fake Jesus reincarnations

Tags: belief, reincarnation

Is the Church (Body of Christ) active in any way, to expose [fake Jesus reincarnations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_claimed_to_be_Jesus)?

For clarification: are there any missions that include reaching the victims of false Jesus reincarnations that one could join?

Comment: Yes ... on Wikipedia! :)

Comment: according to which denomination?

Comment: @JanDvorak according to the Word of God.

Comment: Some people on this SE seem to believe in fake Jesus reincarnations. This question doesn't seem to be very popular.

Comment: The original question seemed clear enough. Still, its edit is even clearer; this should be re-opened. The answer is clear: it is either "no," or it is "Yes, [elaboration on groups/events/outreaches which do the exposing of victim-outreach]". Whether people disagree about the truth/falsity of a specific Jesus reincarnation claim is irrelevant; even people of the same denomination disagree on many points, all that matters is that a group of people believe a reincarnation claim is fake and do they expose it and/or help the victims.

Comment: As for the denomination: that does not matter for an initial exploratory question which asks "Does anyone do this *at all*?" Otherwise we would have a dozen questions here: "Do the catholics do x... no." "Do the Methodists do x... no." "Do the Mormons do x... no." "Do the Baptists do x... no." "Do the a do x... no." "Do the b do x... no." "Do the c do x... yes." "Oh finally a yes! Now I'll ask further questions." It is a much better idea to keep the introductory, exploratory question as 1, then follow-up questions can be about the individual denominations to explore further and more detailed.

Comment: Hmm, on closer inspection, OP's comment to the second answer makes it appear that an answer much more granular than a denomination is acceptable, more even than a group of people; OP would accept an answer of a specific person saying "Yes, I do that personally, therefore the church is active in that." and technically, if you split hairs, that can answer the question as worded. That does make it `too broad`; that makes me almost say never mind about re-opening, except that a proper answer to this question would be useful to others - I'm torn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no, depending on what you mean by "active".

According to orthordox Christian teachings, **there will be no re-incarnation of Jesus**. His next appearance will be in glory and judgement when nobody on earth will be in a position to question the description given of Jesus current position:

> **[Philippians 2:9-11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+2:9-11&version=ESV)** (ESV)
>   <sup>9</sup>  Therefore God has highly exalted him and bestowed on him the name that is above every name, <sup>10</sup>  so that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, <sup>11</sup>  and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

In other words, according to the main traditions claiming to be Christian (Catholic, Orthodox, and Protestant alike) anybody in any circumstance currently claiming to be a re-incarnation of Jesus is a fraud. As long as there is wiggle room for anybody on the planet to deny such a claim, the denial sticks.

This belief makes it really easy to root out the fakes:

```
FOR applicant IN jesus_reincarnations RETURN legitimate=false;
```

If by 'active' you mean:

- "Do we examine the circumstances of every applicant and keep a running list of possibilities?"

  Then no. That would be a waste of time.
- "Do we have a clear and definitive answer for whether such applicants are frauds?"

  Then yes. All of them.

Comment: I mean, 'active' as in exposing the Word, that what you [@Caleb] had explained, to those people that believe that these 'frauds' are somehow a reincarnation of Jesus.

Comment: Is "should" in Philippians 2:9-11 a bad translation of the original text? Your position would be better supported if it said "will". "Should" indicates that it would be best if they did, but not necessarily that they will.

Comment: @Robert The ESV translation has some hold over phrasing from much older English than you are perhaps used to seeing (it's from the same translation family as the KJV and has kept some wording choices from ASV). The sense here in the original is very emphatic indeed—more so even than "will" conveys in strictly modern parlance. You'll find it translated "will" in some translations, but the language construct here is not a bad translation, it's just one you're not accustomed to and hence don't feel the force of.

Comment: Jesus' own words on re-incarnation claims, Luke 21:8 "He replied: 'Watch out that you are not deceived. For many will come in my name, claiming, "I am he," and, "The time is near." Do not follow them.'"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I personally have warned others about the false return and / or reincarnation of Jesus.  The Bible itself warns us about this (at least in reference to the tribulation), and this is the passage I point to:

> [Mat 24:23-27 NKJV] 23 "Then if anyone says to you, 'Look, here [is] the Christ!' or 'There!' do not believe [it]. 24 "For false christs and false prophets will rise and show great signs and wonders to deceive, if possible, even the elect. 25 "See, I have told you beforehand. 26 "Therefore if they say to you, 'Look, He is in the desert!' do not go out; [or] 'Look, [He is] in the inner rooms!' do not believe [it]. 27 "For as the lightning comes from the east and flashes to the west, so also will the coming of the Son of Man be.

When Jesus returns, we will know it!

Comment: I'd like to mark this as the answer too!! Great to hear that you've warned others personally.