# If someone claims himself to be Jesus Christ does The Bible tell me to immediately disbelieve him?

Tags: christology, reference-request

I, as a Christian, believe everything in The Bible.
Then I meet a man who claims himself to be Jesus Christ.
Can I immediately disbelieve that man based on some arguments from The Bible?

Comment: We know Jesus is coming back, and at that time he will want his followers to know who he is. On the other hand, he said that many false prophets will come in his name. So he must expect that we will evaluate the claims.

Comment: He could have already came back and we didn't believe him.

Comment: @disciple How can I evaluate the claim if not by using The Bible?

Comment: @The Freemason If my beliefs are postulated by The Bible then The Bible shall give me a method to accept or refuse the claim. How do I proceed?

Comment: if you believe everything in the Bible, hopefully, you've read it and know Jesus' teachings and miracles. If someone claims to be Christ then he should teach the same things and be able to perform miracles like he did in the Bible

Comment: Related: [What was the Biblical basis for testing the truthfulness of every statement made by 'real' Prophets or Apostles?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14632)

Comment: Also, [Fake Jesus reincarnations](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/27694/13677) is closed but has an answer that is relevant.

Comment: @depperm I fail to see why? Same teachings seems logical but why the same miracles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are referring to Christ's second coming:**

Your story implies that Jesus has come in some sort of secret way. Consider the implications of
[1 Thessalonians 4:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians%204):

> For the Lord himself will come down from heaven, with a loud command, with the voice of the archangel and with the trumpet call of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first. (NIV)

When Christ's overt return is upon us, it will be apparent. If you didn't notice Him coming down from the heavens, if you didn't hear the trumpet call and the voice of the archangel, if you didn't see the dead in Christ rise, then it's very likely you are not talking to the risen Christ in His magnificent glory.

Also, Christ warned us himself that many false prophets and false messiahs will come ([Matthew 24:4, 11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024) and [Luke 21:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2021)). At that point, you might find it useful to [learn how the Bible teaches us to test the prophets.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14632)

**If you are referring to Christ's first coming:**

If you are fully convinced that Christ has already come in the 1st century, then any prospective Christ would first need to convince you that Jesus was *not* the Christ. Convincing you of that is a highly personal thing. *What would it take to convince you that Jesus was not the Christ?* Then, if you got to that point, this new prospective Christ would have to fulfill the Old Testament prophecies about himself. There's disagreement about those prophecies, but generally it is agreed that *at least* he must be a born man in the line of David.

Comment: I see! Now perfectly clear! I was referring to the second coming and now it's clear!

Comment: To reinforce the main point about the second coming, consider Matthew 24:27 "For as the lightning cometh out of the east, and shineth even unto the west; so shall also the coming of the Son of man be." When Christ returns, it will be completely obvious to everyone.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, that one too is indicative of the 2nd coming being quite a site. There's also others in Revelation, but I neglected to mention those for the sake of brevity.